# Combine two columns together as a list data type and filter out words from a suppression json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I want to create a new column called 'topic' by combining two columns as a list within the dataframe. Also the words needs to be filter from my json supression file.

Input CSV circuits file:

```
location                 country           
Melbourne, Australia     Australia   
Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia   Malaysia
Sakhir                   Bahrain
Istanbul, Turkey         Turkey 
Monte-Carlo              Monaco


df = pd.read_csv("circuits.csv")    

def dedup(value):
    words = set(value.split(', '))    
    return ', '.join(words)

def worldplay(frame):
    
    #print(df.head(3))
    df['topic'] = df['location'] + ", " + df['country']
    df["topic"] = df['topic'].str.split(', ').apply(set).str.join(', ')
    df['topic'] = df["topic"].apply(dedup)
    
    f = open('exclude.json',) 
    data = json.load(f) 
    index= json.dumps(data["topic"])
    res = [item for item in df['topic'] if item not in index] 
    res_o = [x for xs in res for x in xs.split(',')]
    df['topic'] = res_o   

worldplay(df)
```

Json File:

```
{
"topic": [
    "Australia", "Melbourne", "Malaysia"
]    
}
```

I want my output to be:

All the strings in the exclude.json file should be takeout on the 'Topic' column.

```
location                 country           topic
Melbourne, Australia     Australia,        []
Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia   Malaysia          ['Kuala Lumpur']
Sakhir                   Bahrain           ['Bahrain', 'Sakhir']
Istanbul, Turkey         Turkey            ['Turkey', 'Istanbul']
Monte-Carlo              Monaco            ['Monte-Carlo', 'Monaco']
```

Comment: Can you add more information on your question, you are skipping many details... what is a suppression file? What exactly do you want to achieve? It seems you want to achieve more than you ask. Having the `wordplay` performing operations in a global `df` is not a good start. Would pass it as a parameter. Are the columns always text?

Comment: All the columns are texts. The suppression file is the json file which contain certain words I don't want on my "Topic" column inside a list.

Comment: post the sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

locations = [
    ['Melbourne', 'Australia'],
    ['Kuala Lumpur'],
    ['Sakhir'],
    ['Istanbul'], 
    ['Monte-Carlo'],
]

countries = [
    'Australia',
    'Malaysia',
    'Bahrain',
    'Turkey',
    'Monaco',
]

my_mapping = {
    'country': countries,
    'location': locations,
}

my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_mapping)

not_wanted_stuff = {'Australia', 'Melbourne', 'Malaysia'}

def create_topic_column_on_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    df['topic'] = None
    for i, (country, cities) in enumerate(zip(df.country, df.location)):
        my_set = set([country, *cities])
        my_set -= not_wanted_stuff
        df.loc[i, 'topic'] = list(my_set)
        
create_topic_column_on_df(my_df)
print(my_df)
```

The output is:

```
     country                location                  topic
0  Australia  [Melbourne, Australia]                     []
1   Malaysia          [Kuala Lumpur]         [Kuala Lumpur]
2    Bahrain                [Sakhir]      [Bahrain, Sakhir]
3     Turkey              [Istanbul]     [Istanbul, Turkey]
4     Monaco           [Monte-Carlo]  [Monte-Carlo, Monaco]
```

I would make it more general purpose than above... but that answers your question.

**EDIT**
For the `topics` and its reading from the json you can:

```
import json
with open('path_to_json', 'r') as f:
    topics = set(json.load(f).get('topic', None))
    print(topics)
```

My output:
`{'Australia', 'Malaysia', 'Melbourne'}`

**EDIT2**
What if the location is a single string containing different cities:

```
import pandas as pd

locations = [
    'Melbourne, Australia',
    'Kuala Lumpur',
    'Sakhir',
    'Istanbul', 
    'Monte-Carlo',
]

countries = [
    'Australia',
    'Malaysia',
    'Bahrain',
    'Turkey',
    'Monaco',
]

my_mapping = {
    'country': countries,
    'location': locations,
}

my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_mapping)

not_wanted_stuff = {'Australia', 'Melbourne', 'Malaysia'}


def create_topic_column_on_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    df['topic'] = None
    for i, (country, cities) in enumerate(zip(df.country, df.location)):
        cities = cities.split(', ')
        my_set = set([country, *cities])
        my_set -= not_wanted_stuff
        df.loc[i, 'topic'] = list(my_set)
        
create_topic_column_on_df(my_df)
print(my_df)
```

The output is exactly the same as mentioned in the original answer.

Comment: Thank you but the location's column has multiple strings on a column's cells therefore it won't be a list at the start.

Comment: Can you be more precise about multiple strings? If 'Melbourne, Australia' then you can do a simple split operation like on your original question. That means, applying a `.split(', ')` within the `create_topic_column_on_df` on every entry of `df.location`: `cities = cities.split(', ')` would solve your problem.

Comment: Cheers works with this dataset. I tired with another dataset with the same fields and I'm getting ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '). Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you post a piece of the dataset?